# Weird preg_match error

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a very weird error from preg_match command.

If I set the $test as (for example) `$test = 'XtzTy';` it's working perfectly.

BUT

since $test is not static it's not working even if the value IS `XtzTy`

So I thought to convert it to string so I was using

```
$test= settype($test, 'string');
```

but it still NOT working !!!

This is my EXTREMELY SIMPLE preg_match compare tool :

```
if (preg_match('~(XtzTy|bb9c3)~',$test)) {
    echo 'String Found!';
}
```

If both of them is STRING and the value of $test is `XtzTy` AND converted to string why it's not working ?

Comment: From where are you getting the `XtzTy` ?

Comment: The type of variable is not the problem. In a weakly typed language a function like peg_match gets a string from whatever you feed into.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran - $test is md5 encryption

Comment: @arkascha so how come it's not working ?!

Comment: You use phps `settype()` function incorrect. It returns a bool. Just take a look at the documentation. Makes sense: you specify the variable to be converted as a reference.

Comment: @arkascha $test= strval($test); still NOT working !

Comment: What does `var_dump($test);` results in ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran XtzTy

Comment: `echo "test='$test'\n";` to see if you have extra cruft such as a newline in $test. By the way, use ^ and $ to anchor your pattern, if that's the _only_ thing that should be found in $test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `$test` in string like this:

```
$str_test = (string) $test;
```

**OR** Use only this regex

`(XtzTy|bb9c3)` without `~`

**OR**

`/(XtzTy|bb9c3)/`

Comment: I tried this also and ~i on the preg_match... both of them not working :/

Comment: Send var_dump($test) just before pregmatch please

Comment: I didn't find a solution here but solve it in a different way but thanks EVERYONE here for trying to help ! I would accept your answer anyways ! :)

Comment: The $test was md5 generated dynamically and taking the request_uri in consideration and I was using this file as include so when I was testing it directly on the page the md5 was different than the request_uri that request the $test value from other page because (not only but one of the parameters was) the request_uri was different :)

Comment: Perl regular expression matching _requires_ a delimiter at the beginning and end of the pattern. Use something, such as ~ or / that is not found in the pattern itself.